# SQL IN in WHERE. How smart is the optimizer?

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I have the following query to execute:

```
UPDATE scenario_group 
    SET 
        project_id = @projectId 
    WHERE
        scenario_group_id = @scenarioGroupId 
        AND @projectId IN (SELECT project_id FROM project);";
```

To me that looks like it would evaluate the `@projectId IN (SELECT project_id FROM PROJECT)` for every matching row. That would be bad. On the other hand, if the optimizer is smart it would see that the projects table never changes and therefore only do that check once.

This is the EXPLAIN. That looks like it would be doing the IN a lot. But I'm not sure how to interpret it.

```
id  parent  notused detail
3   0   0   SEARCH TABLE scenario_group USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
8   0   0   USING ROWID SEARCH ON TABLE project FOR IN-OPERATOR
```

Do I need to rewrite this update? If so, how would I write this UPDATE to explicitly check for the existence of the `project_id` in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXISTS` is often more efficient than `IN`.  So I would just write the logic as:

```
UPDATE scenario_group 
    SET project_id = @projectId 
    WHERE scenario_group_id = @scenarioGroupId AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM project p WHERE p.project_id = @projectId);
```

In particular, this will make use of an index on `project(project_id)` -- which seems quite likely given that `project_id` should be the primary key.

Comment: You're right, project_id is the primary key. And indeed the EXPLAIN for the EXIST version now shows it using it.